# Twitter Bootstrap modals: inputs are invisible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

What's wrong with this code? No inputs show up, but the buttons in the modal footer do. Any idea what's going on here?

```
<div class="modal" style="display: none;" id="customArticleModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Add your own article</h3>
  </div>
  <%= form_for(@custom_article) do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :description %>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.submit "Create", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Here's the rendered source:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="customArticleModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3>Add your own article</h3>
  </div>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/components" class="new_component" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_component" method="post">
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input id="component_name" name="component[name]" size="30" type="text" />
      <input id="component_description" name="component[description]" size="30" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create article" />
    </div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you added the data-toggle="modal" to the element that triggers modal?

Comment: Your question title references Bootstrap, but I believe this has to do with server side code and not client side - which Bootstrap is. What is the rendered HTML?

Comment: It's a client-side question. Inputs aren't rendered despite the rendered HTML saying they are. They're just hidden somehow.

Comment: Please show the rendered html on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a bit of jQuery to override whatever Bootstrap was doing here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#custom_article_form .control-group .controls input').css('display', 'block');
  $('#custom_article_form .control-group .controls textarea').css('display', 'block');
});
```

No idea why it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal" style="display: none;" id="customArticleModal">
```

Here you have manually added the style as display: none. Instead of that try using bootstrap class. e.g.

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="customArticleModal">
```

Comment: That doesn't make a difference: the jQuery overwrites that. It's the  inputs _in_ the modal that don't get shown.

Comment: ohho.. question: on shown up the modal, does your style change to "dispaly: block" ?

Comment: Yeah, it changes to `display: block;`.